# How to define a type conversion from std::string to a custom type?

Tags: c++, string, operators, type-conversion

Conversion operators are declared inside a class like this:

```
operator string();
```

When declared, they can be defined like this;

```
Foo::operator string(){ return stringRep; }
```

*How can I define a conversion operator from string to my custom type?*

Answer (score 0):

Write a constructor that takes a string.

Comment: Pretty straight forward, no doubt about that, but is that really the only way? :(

Comment: @iFreilicht Why do anything more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

A conversion operator/function `operator Tc`, of a Class of type Ty is a non static member function which converts the Type Ty to some specified type.

If you need to convert from string, which is a Class of type `std::basic_string<char>` to a Type of `Tc`, either

1. `std::basic_string`, needs to provide a Type conversion function, or
2. you need to provide a constructor in the Class of Type Tc that accepts an object of type `std::basic_string<char>`.